# 401 raised before 405 in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have this simple viewset that allows to create, retrieve and list a model :

```
class GenreViewset(CreateListRetrieveViewset):
    """
    Creates, lists and retrieves genres.
    """

    serializer_class = GenreSerializer
    queryset = Genre.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

When I test the corresponding endpoint for a PUT request, I expect to get a 405 status. However, that's not the case when a user is not authenticated, a 401 error is raised first. It's only when a user is authenticated that a 405 error is raised.

Why is that and is it possible to force 405 to appear before 401 ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The API responds with a 405 error to indicate that the client tried to use an HTTP method that the resource does not allow.

A 401 error response indicates that the client tried to operate on a protected resource without providing the proper authorization. A 401 is raised as the client is not allowed in a protected space.

I don't know if you really want to eliminate PUT from your allowed methods, but that's irrelevant. When it comes to 405 before 401, I don't think that will ever happen as a user is allowed a HTTP method on an endpoint only if it is authorized to do so. So, **Authentication of a user always comes before method not allowed.** Logically, you can guess the reason why. Let's say you don't have a ticket to travel where you want to go, that is a problem yes but if you don't have a passport the former problem is irrelevant.